# Laravel get data from relationship

Tags: php, laravel

How to get the question by tag name or tag ID with Laravel, example like this page get the question by tag: Python

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python

Example for my relationship:

post:
  id

tags:
  id

post_tag:
  post_id,
  tag_id

Comment: Tag is going to need a name, not just an ID value.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data structure (you should update with it):

By id

```
$my_tag_id = 1;
$my_posts = Post::where('tag_id',$my_tag_id )->get();
```

By name

```
$my_tag_name = 'python';
$my_posts = Post::where('tag_id',Tags::where('tag_name',$my_tag_name)->first()->id)->get();
```

Update with yours relationship and we can get a close approach

Comment: as you say, we can not get tag relation of question

Answer (score 0):

```php
// in post tag model
public function Tag() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Tag::class);
}

public function Post() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
}

---

$post = PostTag::with(['Tag', 'Post'])->where([
    'post_id' => $post_id, 
    'tag_id' => $tag_id
])->first();
```

Comment: I think the question is to filter posts by name or tag ID. You only get the tag with one post in your query.

Answer (score 0):

The best Laravel way to do this is to filter posts using relationship tags with `whereHas` or `whereRelation`.

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model 
{
    public function tags() 
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class);
    }
}

---

$name = 'python';
$id = '123';

$post = Post::whereHas('tags', function ($query) use ($name, $id) {
    $query->where('name', $name)
        ->orWhere('id', $id);
})->get();

// OR

$post = Post::whereRelation('tags', 'name', $name)->orWhereRelation('tags', 'id', $id)->get();
```

Read more here: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#inline-relationship-existence-queries